# Not all UIButtons inside tableviewcell are working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UItableview thats populated from Parse and i have a few buttons in the cellForRowAtIndexPath like so

```
    UIbutton *buttonTwo = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    buttonTwo.selected = NO;
    [[buttonTwo layer] setBorderWidth:2];
    [[buttonTwo layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];

    UIButton *buttonOne = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
    [buttonOne addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOne:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[buttonOne layer] setBorderWidth:2];
    [[buttonOne layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
```

The issue is that when say for example there is 5 Cells populated, not every cell will have the button loaded, but when i click on a button that refreshes the data only then it comes. ill link a picture.

here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIs2v.jpg

so the big white space would be an image. but where on the top it has button1 and button2 there both loaded correctly, but on the second row button2 isnt correctly loaded, and its inactive untill i click refresh where it reloads Parse Data only then the border for the button shows and is clickable.

Here's more of the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIbutton *buttonTwo = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        buttonTwo.selected = NO;
        [[buttonTwo layer] setBorderWidth:2];
        [[buttonTwo layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];



        UIButton *buttonOne = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
        [buttonOne addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOne:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [[buttonOne layer] setBorderWidth:2];
        [[buttonOne layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: A problem with cell reuse? a) Where is this code you posted, where do the buttons get added to the cell? Show us more of cellForRowAtIndexPath, or the init method for your cell class b) What are you doing inside prepareForReuse?

Comment: you didnt provide enough info. That image looks like you have 5 elements in one cell, but not 5 cells!!!

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, the button1 and button2 are from the first cell on top, i have it scrolled down to show that the second cell's button 2 isnt loading properly with the border and isnt clickable.

Comment: All I can see is you are trying to obtain button using `(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:6]` but where are you creating and initializing them?

Comment: i thought i wouldnt need to do alloc and init

Comment: how would i create and initialize them?

Comment: the reason i didnt do any creating or initializing is because i have it in my storyboard

Comment: Just keep a debug breakpoint after line `viewWithTag:` and see if you are able to retrieve buttonTwo / buttonOne.

Comment: how should i be creating the button?

Comment: it says `buttonOne = (UIButton *) nil `